# Android: how to multiply values from EditText?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, multiplication

Ok, first thing is that I am new in `Android` development, please do not shoot me for the question.

So, I am developing an app yhat needs to multiply from 3 `EditTexts`:

```
resultsEditText
amountEditText
taxEditText
```

They are set with the same name in the `R.java`.  what I want is  the following:

```
amountEditText * taxEditText = resultsEditText
```

I have no idea in how to implement this, I have searched the internet and this site, which I use as a reference for all my Android development needs, and all the code I found doesnt work at all.  I dont know what else to do.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set EditText input type as number as well so user can input only numbers.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(resultsEditText.getText().toString().toTrim());
int b = Integer.parseInt(amountEditText.getText().toString().toTrim());
int c = Integer.parseInt(taxEditText.getText().toString().toTrim());

    int result = a * b * c;
```

Comment: hag to change .toTrim() to trim() because Eclipse error out, also now that I put the code you told me, Eclipse says that there is a missing ; ) or }

Answer (score 0):

```
    Button btnCal,btnSub;
    EditText editLen,editWid,editFeet;
    int a,b,res;

        btnSub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSub);
        btnCal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCal);

        editLen=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editLen);
        editWid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editWid);
        editFeet=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editFeet);

        btnCal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                a = Integer.parseInt(editLen.getText().toString());
                b = Integer.parseInt(editWid.getText().toString());

                res=a*b;
                editFeet.setText(String.valueOf(res));

            }
        });
```